# Why do I get a routing error when doing a delete action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

When I do a `delete`, I get a routing error:

```
Routing Error
No route matches [POST] "/items/10pp-logo"
```

Don't worry, `current_user.items.find(params[:id])` does find the correct record for `/items/10pp-logo`.

This is the link in the view for my `Delete` action on my `item` object:

```
<td><%= link_to "<i class='fa fa-trash-o'></i>".html_safe, item, method: :destroy, data: { confirm: "Are you sure you want to delete #{item.name}?" } %></td>
```

This is the action in the controller:

```
  def destroy
    @item = current_user.items.find(params[:id])
    @item.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to items_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
```

All the JS is being rendered in the footer - i.e. below where the delete action in the view is rendered (not sure if that makes a difference).

This is in my model - `Item.rb`:

```
  belongs_to :owner, :class_name => "User",
  :foreign_key => "user_id"
```

This is the items route:

```
resources :items
```

I have the 7 RESTful actions in my controller and 2 nonRESTFul ones - for which I have 2 separate routes for.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the HTTP method should be :delete not :destroy. It defaults to :post, which is what you're getting.